# Are there any canon non-humanoid Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, aliens, jedi

I am aware that there were many very strange creatures among the many books and comics such as sentient mountains.  Some of these even became Jedi like Ikrit (an alien bunny like animal).  While some strange creatures still exist in canon like sarlaacs, I cannot remember any strange Jedi.  The closest I can think of is Yoda who is a very short humanoid.

**Excluding Yoda, are there any canon Jedi who are not humanoid?**

I will define humanoid as naturally having:

- two arms
- two legs
- No additional limbs besides those listed and (possibly) a tail
- a clearly defined head at the top of the body
- eyes, mouth, ears, or similar features on head in roughly the same locations
- roughly human size and proportions (why Yoda is explicitly exempt)
- solid organic (or similar) composition

Darth Vader counts as humanoid despite his robotic exterior and lack of natural limbs as he underwent extreme body modifications.

Comment: To be clear I am explicitly differentiating between Disney's "Legends" and "Canon" continuities.

Comment: Actually it's a grey area whether the "Jedi Path Manual" (which contains multiple non-humanoid jedi) is considered part of the Disney canon. The press-release indicated that Del Rey books would be considered canonical, then failed to mention in their list of recognised exceptions; http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/the-new-star-wars-canon-guide/

Comment: Did General Griveous give you the idea of this question?

Comment: @b_jonas no, the thought process started from the insane variety of green lanterns (specifically the smallpox, planet, and equation ones).  I wondered if the biological explanation (midiclorians) limited the diversity of species (compared to an emotional one in green lantern) or the "ancient ancestor" theory could hold for force sensitive species. I knew there was Ikrit, the jedi floating in a jar, and force sensitive crystal beings working robots but I think they all are now non-canon.

Comment: I know he was non-canon even before the Disney acquisition, but I don't think this question should go without mention of [Skippy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skippy_the_Jedi_Droid).

Comment: @KSmarts I really wanted to sneak him in, but I have to keep it serious.  Though does the tutor droid from Clone Wars (voiced by David Tennant) count? He does have a lot of experience with jedi lore.

Comment: Silly side note: Here's an argument that none of the characters are humanoid; they're just presented that way in the movies because those are the actors available on Earth. Star Wars is really about bees.  http://www.tor.com/blogs/2014/04/every-human-in-star-wars-is-really-a-humanoid-bee

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Oppo Rancisis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Oppo_Rancisis) was a Thisspiasian Jedi Master.  You see him in the council chambers in *The Phantom Menace*.  His species is serpentine, so while he does have a head and two arms, he doesn't have legs.  While it still has mostly humanoid characteristics, this was the only one that at least didn't have humanoid legs.

[image]

Also, if Yoda has been included in the list of "non-humanoid" then there is also [Yaddle](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yaddle), who is a female Yoda. Also seen in *The Phantom Menace*.

[image]

[Pong Krell](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pong_Krell) is a Besalisk, he has four arms but a mostly humanoid structure.  He was in the *Clone Wars* TV series (awesome thing about him was the dual wielding double bladed light sabers)

[image]

Another from the *Clone Wars* TV series is the Ithorian Jedi [Byph](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Byph).

[image]

Credit goes to Richard and Null for adding in images and helping find better canon examples.

Comment: @Richard I know in the Clone Wars cartoon (tv series not miniseries) we see a jedi the same species as Dex.  4 arms, so I guess kinda non-humanoid.

Comment: Jedi Pong Krell is the 4 armed one (same species as Dex) who @CBredlow mentioned.  He is Besalisk.

Comment: Is there a reason your link says Byph is Legends?

Comment: @kaine Hmm, that is weird, no I don't know why it says Legends when the Clone Wars tv series is canon.

Comment: @CBredlow it is a wiki so there can easily be mistakes.  I don't even know whether he is non-humanoid by definition (and he is refered to as humanoid on that page) as he just has a funny shaped head.  He is weird enough in comparison to the others, however, I like him there.

Comment: Was Oppo Rancisis in The Clone Wars? I remember a scene, I believe it was one of the season 6 final episodes where Yoda was going on his "vision quest" and the Council gathered around him to meditate. IIRC, there was a serpentine Jedi in that scene.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe Maybe? I can't remember the final section too well.  However, I do know he's in the Clone Wars miniseries and he was against making Anakin a Knight just yet.

Comment: What about Yarael Poof? If Yoda is included for his small proportions, then surely Poof should be included as well.

Comment: @Omegacron I'll have to go and look at it and update my answer then.

Comment: The Clone Wars belongs to both canons.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know how far your definition of "canon" stretches but I'd like to submit these I found on Wookieepedia, all who appeared in some book or another:
Beldorion the Hutt
[image: Beldorion the Hutt]
Thon the Tchuukthai
[image: Thon the Tchuukthai]
Ooroo the Celegian
[image: Ooroo the Celegian]

Honorable mention because of the exotic appearance but I can't find any canon references:
Omo Bouri the Wol Cabasshite
[image: Omo Bouri the Wol Cabasshite]

Comment: I believe these are all probably classified under the "Legends" continuity.  There used to be several different levels of canon in the Star Wars universe.  Disney decided to label the movies, the clone wars show, and some other media as "Canon" and then place anything else that had formerly been undersome other level as "Legends".  I know Ooroo and Thon are Legends and the hutt probably is too.  I don't recognize Omo.

Comment: I'm reluctantly downvoting because the answer was explictly looking for fully canon references, not those from the "Legends". If you're struggling to keep up, I've penned an article for the blog that runs through the major difference post-April; http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/the-new-star-wars-canon-guide/

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I'm not deep in Star Wars knowledge and I'll be more careful in the future.

Comment: Beldorion actually fighting with that lightsaber is a hilarious mental image.

Comment: @KSmarts It'd be like a Jedi T-Rex! "*BBSHZOOoo* ... *wzooh wzooh* ... Come closer!"

Comment: Is... is that some sort of narwhale slug or something?